# Why can't I install python using scoop?

Tags: python, scoop-installer

I was trying to install python using scoop, here is the process I tried:

```
scoop install python
WARN  Purging previous failed installation of dark.
ERROR 'dark' isn't installed correctly.
Removing older version (3.11.2).
'dark' was uninstalled.
WARN  Scoop uses 'aria2c' for multi-connection downloads.
WARN  Should it cause issues, run 'scoop config aria2-enabled false' to disable it.
WARN  To disable this warning, run 'scoop config aria2-warning-enabled false'.
Installing 'dark' (3.11.2) [64bit] from main bucket
Starting download with aria2 ...
Download: 07/01 00:31:47 [ERROR] CUID#8 - Download aborted. URI=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScoopInstaller/BinaryDownload: Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:312] errorCode=1 Network problem has occurred. cause:The requested address is Download: Download Results:
Download: gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
Download: ======+====+===========+=======================================================
Download: 61026e|ERR |       0B/s|D:/scoop/cache/dark#3.11.2#https_raw.githubusercontent.com_ScoopInstaller_Binary_master_dark_dark-3.11.2.zip
Download: Status Legend:
Download: (ERR):error occurred.
Download: aria2 will resume download if the transfer is restarted.
Download: If there are any errors, then see the log file. See '-l' option in help/man page for details.

ERROR Download failed! (Error 1) An unknown error occurred
ERROR https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScoopInstaller/Binary/master/dark/dark-3.11.2.zip
    referer=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScoopInstaller/Binary/master/dark/
    dir=D:\scoop\cache
    out=dark#3.11.2#https_raw.githubusercontent.com_ScoopInstaller_Binary_master_dark_dark-3.11.2.zip

ERROR & 'D:\scoop\apps\aria2\current\aria2c.exe' --input-file='D:\scoop\cache\dark.txt' --user-agent='Scoop/1.0 (+http://scoop.sh/) PowerShell/5.1 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Desktop)' --allow-overwrite=true --auto-file-renaming=false --retry-wait=2 --split=5 --max-connection-per-server=5 --min-split-size=5M --console-log-level=warn --enable-color=false --no-conf=true --follow-metalink=true --metalink-preferred-protocol=https --min-tls-version=TLSv1.2 --stop-with-process=9296 --continue --summary-interval=0 --auto-save-interval=1

Please try again or create a new issue by using the following link and paste your console output:
https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/issues/new?title=dark%403.11.2%3a+download+via+aria2+failed
```

Obviously,there are some problems in installing dark,but I don't know why.
Please offer me some advice,I would really appreciate it .

I have already changed my networks and turned off my firewall, but it didn't work.

Comment: See the part where it says "Should it cause issues, run 'scoop config aria2-enabled false' to disable it."? Did you try doing that? What happened when you tried doing that?

Answer (score 1):

i uesd to meet with the same question,i stopped aria2 to solve it